# Mobiscroll Both Date and Time Picker

Tags: cordova, datepicker, datetimepicker, timepicker, mobiscroll

The Mobiscroll website seems to imply that it's possible to have a picker that displays both the date and time

"Date, Time or Both
Use it as just a date picker or time picker or choose the full date & time"

However from their documentation and examples I'm not able to figure out how to get the picker to display both date and time wheels. Anybody know if this is possible and how to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation ([Getting started](http://docs.mobiscroll.com/295)):

```
$(function(){
    // create a datetimepicker with default settings
    $("#scroller").mobiscroll().datetime();
});
```

Demo here: http://demo.mobiscroll.com/datetime/datetime/